# Percentage of Total by Category (BUT data type is Text)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting my first Power BI dashboard to display visuals relating to HR Absenteeism data.
I need to display data by Division on stats relating to absenteeism duration and specific days of the week as a percentage of the Division total rather than Grand Total. I have had success in DAX script for columns containing numbers however these columns contain words (0-3 days, 3.1-5 days & Tuesday, Wednesday). The DAX code is not working for these, I can only assume because they are not number values.

This is the code I have used
Percentage of day category = Var daycategorysum = SUM(Data[Days category])
Var Division = CALCULATE ( SUM(Data[Division]) , REMOVEFILTERS(Data[Division]))
return
daycategorysum/Division

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Correct, you will need to use `SWITCH` to translate the text to numbers, in a Calculated Column or in a `SUMX`.

Comment: Thank you, Could you help me with that script/process? I'm teaching myself so I'm a little behind.